# Safe to turn off power by removing a plug fuse indefinitely?

Tags: safety

I'm trying to turn off the power for my dining room light and as I live in an old apartment, my fuse box only has plug fuses (and a main fuse you pull out).  My plan is to cap the AC wires in the ceiling as I am going to use a 5v 2A adapter for an LED pendant I designed.  So my question is, is it safe for me to simply remove the plug fuse that powers the dining room and leave it out, with the socket exposed?

I have experience with wiring and working with micro controllers and LED strips, but not AC and fuse boxes.  In terms of safety equipment, I have rubber gloves (not thick though) and leather gloves, safety glasses and a voltage tester.  Please let me know if there is anything else I should know regarding proper equipment.

Thanks and I appreciate your help

[image: panel]

[image: fuses]

Comment: Removing a fuse is like opening a breaker, which is what I would do. I don't know about leaving the fuse socket exposed indefinitely though. Is there some lockout you can put in its place?

Comment: I'll ask for this question to be transferred to SE DIY. | However, leaving an open fuse socket is a safety hazard. You could remove the fuse wire and reinsert the holder. Labelling the fuse as "do not use" would also add to 'safety' but may not meet code. I assume that operating the LED pendant supply from the existing wiring is not an option.

Comment: The fuse that powers that light  fixture probably powers other lights or outlets, so you may not want to leave the fuse out.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was thinking of a placeholder...didn't know the correct term for it though; lockout.  Thanks!

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes labeling the lockout would be a very good idea indeed. I'm not sure how I would use the existing wiring to power my Arduino Uno.  I imagine it would be way too much power.

Comment: @PeterBennett that's true; I have thought of that.  I didn't test taking out the fuse yet, but it likely powers the outlets in my dining room as well.  Is it possible to take the fuse out temporarily, cap the wires with power off and then put the fuse back in?  I just need to remove the existing ceiling light essentially.

Comment: @lakerice That works too. Just screw on some wire nuts to cap off the wires.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks!  Good to know.

Comment: You may want to consult an electrician about your local building code. Remember that an insurance company will probably use anything they can to avoid a large payout in the event of a fire, so a minor change like that, if it is not allowed, and even if it has no relationship whatsoever to the cause of an insurance claim, might make your insurance payments all for nothing.

Comment: Yeah. Remove the fuse, cap the wires and then put the fuse back in. That is what I would do. There is no safety hazard associated with capping off wires and leaving them unused inside a closed junction box.

Answer (score 2):

Under no circumstances should you consider removing a fuse to be a means of permanent isolation. Anyone in future might simply replace it, either deliberately or by accident. If you wish to isolate the wiring, you should disconnect it. You could ensure that the tails are properly insulated (e.g. terminate the ends in a terminal block, wrap that thoroughly with electrician's tape) and label them ("dining room ceiling", something like that).

Then you can put the fuse holder in, with or without a fuse in it, and no harm can occur.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a wire fuse, the fuse wire may be removed before replacing the fuse carrier.

Likewise with a cartridge fuse.

Otherwise the outgoing wire from the fuse holder would be required to be disconnected.

The work would require the mains isolator to be switched off, the main fuses to be removed to ensure that the circuit being handled is not live and the off status confirmed using a tester.

Since you do not have prior experience working on mains wiring, it would be advisable to  have a certified electrician to carry out the work.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it is not advisable to remove the fuse plug before removing the main fuses?  I should mention it's a very old style box.  I'm willing to get an electrician if I have to though...I've attached images of the box

Comment: Please describe what's in the photograph.

Comment: Sorry I just uploaded the second pic describing which plug fuses power which areas.  It's a very old building so I imagine this was 1960s style fuses (based on my research).

Comment: What's above the 4 fuses?

Comment: I believe that's the main power.  I haven't pulled it out but from what I have seen in similar old style panels it's 2 cartridge fuses.

Comment: I've got a good idea of your fuse box from the pictures in this site! https://www.kijiji.ca/b-renovation-electrical/ontario/fuse-box/k0c729l9004. You may remove only the dining room / kitchen fuse, make sure that wire is not live and then disconnect and insulate it. You will have to put the fuse back as other loads may be there on the same circuit.